# Unable to host my react app on github. Unable to deploy

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, github

Pushed the app to GitHub, and completed other procedures like updating the package.json file.

Done with `npm install --save gh-pages`
I think this might have something to do with folders because the react stuff is in 'client' folder and rest node, mongo is in the 'api'.

Still unable to deploy it.

package.json

```
{
  "name": "mern-todo-api",
  "homepage": "https://ShreyashDo.github.io/Full-stack-react-todo-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "predeploy": "npm run build",
    "deploy": "gh-pages -d build"
  },
  "author": "Shreyash Dongre",
  "license": "ISC",
  "description": "",
  "dependencies": {
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "gh-pages": "^3.2.3",
    "mongoose": "^6.0.7"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^2.0.12"
  }
}
```

I referred to https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment

[Git-repo](https://github.com/ShreyashDo/Full-stack-react-todo-app)

[Error SS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iIiiU.png)

[Folders SS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e5RPr.png)

Comment: I see that you have both a `client` and an `api` applications, I believe you want to deploy the React app? in the error npm is telling you it couldn't find the `package.json` which is basically true, cuz where u stand at the root `TODO REACT APP` there is no one! maybe a `cd client && npm run deploy` would do the job if u have the deploymeny setup there.

Comment: Yes, I was aware of that but will it deploy the backend part too?

Comment: I tried what you said but I am getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be you are not in the right directory. You need to be inside the client folder where the `package.json` file with object called scripts which has key start, deploy and predeploy is located. You can try this on the terminal.

```
cd client
```

Comment: Yes, but how will that host the full application? Because the backend part is in 'api' folder.

Answer (score 0):

change your deploy in scripts object in `package.json` to :

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "predeploy": "npm run build",
    "deploy": "cd client && gh-pages -d build",
 },
```

Comment: also your git repo does not seem to have any react like code. also don't forget to gitignore node_modules, just saying.

Comment: Getting the same error :(